# matplotlib problems plotting logged data and setting its x/y bounds

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using log plots as follows in matplotlib, roughly as follows.

```
plt.scatter(x, y)

# use log scales
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')

# set x,y limits
plt.xlim([-1, 3])
plt.ylim([-1, 3])
```

The first problem is that without x,y limits, matplotlib sets scales such that most of the data is not visible -- for some reason, it does not use the minimum and maximum values along the x and y dimensions, so the default plot is extremely misleading.

when I do set the limits manually using plt.xlim, plt.ylim, which I interpret to be -1 to 3 in log10 units (i.e. 1/10th to 3000), I get a plot like the one attached.
[image]

The axes labels here don't make sense: it goes from 10^1 to 10^3. What's going on here?

I'm including a more detailed example below that shows all these problems with data:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

x = array([58, 0, 20, 2, 2, 0, 12, 17, 16, 6, 257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 13, 25, 9, 13, 94, 0, 0, 2, 42, 83, 0, 0, 157, 27, 1, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 41, 0, 4, 0, 10, 1, 4, 63, 6, 0, 31, 3, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 0, 0, 17, 52, 46, 15, 67, 20, 0, 0, 20, 39, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 0, 0, 0, 11, 39, 0, 17, 0, 59, 1, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 66, 14, 1, 19, 0, 101, 104, 228, 0, 31])

y = array([60, 0, 9, 1, 3, 0, 13, 9, 11, 7, 177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 31, 10, 14, 80, 0, 0, 2, 30, 70, 0, 0, 202, 26, 1, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 43, 0, 6, 0, 9, 1, 3, 32, 6, 0, 20, 1, 2, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 26, 37, 44, 13, 74, 15, 0, 0, 24, 36, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 0, 0, 9, 40, 0, 14, 0, 51, 2, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 59, 9, 0, 23, 0, 80, 81, 158, 0, 27])

c = 0.01

plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
s = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.title('Unlogged')
s = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.gca().set_yscale('log', basey=2)
plt.title('Logged')
s = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.gca().set_yscale('log', basey=2)
plt.xlim([-2, 20])
plt.ylim([-2, 20])
plt.title('Logged with wrong xlim/ylim')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

This produces the plot below:

[image]

In first subplot from left, we have the raw unlogged data. In second, we have logged values default view. In third we have logged values with x/y lims specified. My questions are:

1. why are the default x/y bounds for the scatter plot wrong? the manual says it's supposed to use the min and max values in the data, but this is obviously not the case here. It picked values that hide the vast majority of data.
2. why is it that when I set the bounds myself, in third scatter plot from left, it reverses the order of the labels? Showing 2^8 before 2^5? It's very confusing.
3. finally, how can I get it so that the plots are not squished like that by default using subplots? I wanted these scatter plots to be square.

EDIT: Thanks to Joe and Honk for reply. If I try to adjust subplots like this to be square:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,3), dpi=10)
s = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1, adjustable='box', aspect='equal')
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.title('Unlogged')
s = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, adjustable='box', aspect='equal')
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.gca().set_yscale('log', basey=2)
plt.title('Logged')
```

I get the result below:

[image]

How can I get so that each plot is square and aligned with each other? It should just be a grid of square, all equal sizes...

EDIT 2:

To contribute something back, here is how one would take these log 2 plots and make the axes appear with their non-exponent notation:

```
import matplotlib

from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def log_2_product(x, pos):
    return "%.2f" %(x)

c = 0.01
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
s1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1, adjustable='box', aspect='equal')
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
plt.title('Unlogged')
plotting.axes_square(s1)
s2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, adjustable='box', aspect='equal')
min_x, max_x = min(x + c), max(x + c)
min_y, max_y = min(y + c), max(y + c)
plotting.axes_square(s2)
plt.xlim([min_x, max_x])
plt.ylim([min_y, max_y])
plt.gca().set_xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.gca().set_yscale('log', basey=2)
plt.scatter(x + c, y + c)
formatter = FuncFormatter(log_2_product)
s2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
s2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.title('Logged')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Most odd! I'm curious to know myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@honk has already answered your main question, but as for the others (and your original question), please read a few tutorials or have a look at some of the examples. :)

You're getting very confused because you haven't looked at the documentation for the functions you're using.

> why are the default x/y bounds for the scatter plot wrong? the manual
>   says it's supposed to use the min and max values in the data, but this
>   is obviously not the case here. It picked values that hide the vast
>   majority of data.

It most certainly does not say that in the documentation.

By default, matplotlib will "round" to the nearest "even" numbers for plot limits. In the case of a log plot, that's the nearest power of the base.

If you want it to strictly snap to the min and max of the data, specify:

```
ax.axis('tight')
```

or equivalently

```
plt.axis('tight')
```

> why is it that when I set the bounds myself, in third scatter plot from left, it reverses the order of the labels? Showing 2^8 before
>   2^5? It's very confusing.

It's not. It's showing 2^-8 before 2^5. You just have too many labels squished in. The minus signs in the exponents are being hidden by overlapping text. Try resizing the plot or calling `plt.tight_layout()` (Or change the font sizes or the dpi. Changing the dpi is a quick way of making all of the fonts larger or smaller on the saved image.)

> finally, how can I get it so that the plots are not squished like that
>   by default using subplots? I wanted these scatter plots to be square.

There are several ways to do this, depending on what you mean by "square".  (i.e. do you want the aspect ratio of the plot to vary or the limits?)

I'm guessing that you mean both, in which case you'd pass in `adjustable='box'` and `aspect='equal'` to `plt.subplot`. (You can also set it later in a number of different ways, (`plt.axis('equal')` etc))

As an example of all of the above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([58, 0, 20, 2, 2, 0, 12, 17, 16, 6, 257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 13, 25,
              9, 13, 94, 0, 0, 2, 42, 83, 0, 0, 157, 27, 1, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
              0, 41, 0, 4, 0, 10, 1, 4, 63, 6, 0, 31, 3, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
              17, 52, 46, 15, 67, 20, 0, 0, 20, 39, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 0, 
              0, 0, 11, 39, 0, 17, 0, 59, 1, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 66, 14, 1, 19, 0, 
              101, 104, 228, 0, 31])

y = np.array([60, 0, 9, 1, 3, 0, 13, 9, 11, 7, 177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 31, 
              10, 14, 80, 0, 0, 2, 30, 70, 0, 0, 202, 26, 1, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
              0, 43, 0, 6, 0, 9, 1, 3, 32, 6, 0, 20, 1, 2, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
              26, 37, 44, 13, 74, 15, 0, 0, 24, 36, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 
              0, 0, 9, 40, 0, 14, 0, 51, 2, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 59, 9, 0, 23, 0, 80,
              81, 158, 0, 27])
c = 0.01

# Let's make the figure a bit bigger so the text doesn't run into itself...
# (5x3 is rather small at 100dpi. Adjust the dpi if you really want a 5x3 plot)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10, 6), 
                         subplot_kw=dict(aspect=1, adjustable='box'))

# Don't use scatter for this. Use plot. Scatter is if you want to vary things 
# like color or size by a third or fourth variable.
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x + c, y + c, 'bo')

for ax in axes[1:]:
    ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
    ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)

axes[0].set_title('Unlogged')
axes[1].set_title('Logged')

axes[2].axis([2**-2, 2**20, 2**-2, 2**20])
axes[2].set_title('Logged with wrong xlim/ylim')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want your plot outlines to be exactly the same size and shape, then the easiest way is to change the figure size to an appropriate ratio and then use `adjustable='datalim'`.

If you want to be fully generalized, just manually add the sub-axes instead of using subplot.

However, if you don't mind adjusting the figure size and/or using `subplots_adjust`, then it's easy to do it and still use subplots.

Basically, you'd do something like

```
# For 3 columns and one row, we'd want a 3 to 1 ratio...
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(9,3), 
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='datalim', aspect='equal')

# By default, the width available to make subplots in is 5% smaller than the 
# height to make them in. This is easily changable...
# ("right" is a percentage of the total width. It will be 0.95 regardless.)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.95)
```

And then continue as before.

For the full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([58, 0, 20, 2, 2, 0, 12, 17, 16, 6, 257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 13, 25,
              9, 13, 94, 0, 0, 2, 42, 83, 0, 0, 157, 27, 1, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
              0, 41, 0, 4, 0, 10, 1, 4, 63, 6, 0, 31, 3, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
              17, 52, 46, 15, 67, 20, 0, 0, 20, 39, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 0, 
              0, 0, 11, 39, 0, 17, 0, 59, 1, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 66, 14, 1, 19, 0, 
              101, 104, 228, 0, 31])

y = np.array([60, 0, 9, 1, 3, 0, 13, 9, 11, 7, 177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 31, 
              10, 14, 80, 0, 0, 2, 30, 70, 0, 0, 202, 26, 1, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
              0, 43, 0, 6, 0, 9, 1, 3, 32, 6, 0, 20, 1, 2, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
              26, 37, 44, 13, 74, 15, 0, 0, 24, 36, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 
              0, 0, 9, 40, 0, 14, 0, 51, 2, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 59, 9, 0, 23, 0, 80,
              81, 158, 0, 27])
c = 0.01

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(9, 3),
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='datalim', aspect='equal'))
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.95)

for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x + c, y + c, 'bo')

for ax in axes[1:]:
    ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
    ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)

axes[0].set_title('Unlogged')
axes[1].set_title('Logged')

axes[2].axis([2**-2, 2**20, 2**-2, 2**20])
axes[2].set_title('Logged with wrong xlim/ylim')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I appreciate it. Just one more follow up: if I use adjustable='box' and aspect='equal', it still does not make the individual subplots square in the same way. See edited reply.

Comment: If you want exactly equal, square outlines for the plots (note that the plots themselves _cannot_ not be square (i.e. aspect=1 and same limits in x and y) in this case!!) then are a few different ways to do it. Give me a bit and I'll add another example.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I don't want them to have the same axes values -- just both be "square" in that x units in one dimension equals x units in the other, for each plot, and that the actual square is the same size in all... thanks

Comment: Thanks for this demonstration. The one last thing I am confused about is: why are the axis ticks logarithmic like they are for the default base 10? The distance between 2**2 and 2**4 is not the same as 2**4 and 2**6, yet the axes plot it as such.

Comment: Well, now I'm confused... That's the definition of a logarithmic plot, right?  By definition you plot things such that `base**n` and `base**(n+1)` are the same distance apart for any `n`, right? Otherwise, it wouldn't be a logarithmic plot with that base?

Comment: To follow up on my last comment, I guess I was looking for something like this in base 2: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/CustomLogLabels   -- is this the best way to do it?  if so I'm all set. Thanks again for all your help everyone

Comment: Ah! I understand now... The example you linked to is one way to do it, but it's slightly round-about.  `FormatStrFormatter` does the same thing. You can just do `formatter = FormatStrFormatter('%i')` and then set the formatter for the x and y axes.

Comment: I already posted my solution in case others are interested. Yours is of course more elegant though I am worried it will misformat values < 1?  With "%i" I sometimes get all zeros for values less than 1, but %.2f will show these as floats.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing what units to give to `xlim` and `ylim`. They **should not** be called `xlim(log10(min), log10(max))` but just `xlim(min, max)`. They deal with the lowest and highest values you want on your axes which are in units of `x` and `y`.

The weird display seems to me to be some bug you trigger since you request a negative minimum on a logarithmic scale which it cannot show (`log(x)>0` for all `x`).

Comment: I accept that for the xlim/ylim, though it is confusing. Do you have any idea about the other two questions?